# Trying to convert xml to a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

My xml looks like:

```
<root>
  <blah1>some text</blah1>
  <someother>blah aasdf</someother>
</root>
```

I want to convert this to a dictionary

So I can do:

```
myDict["blah1"]
```

and it returns the text 'some text'

So far I have:

```
Dictionary<string,string> myDict = (from elem in myXmlDoc.Element("Root").Elements()
                                select elem.Value).ToDictionary<string,string>();
```

Is that correct or do I have to change the select to something with 2 results?

Answer (score 2):

Specify what you want for Key and what for Value.

```
var myDict = myXmlDoc.Elements()
                     .ToDictionary( key => key.Name, val => val.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a lambda in the ToDictionary call so it knows what to use for the key and what to use for the value...

[check here for a good example](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ToDictionaryOperator.ashx), [and here as well](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2009/06/30/linq-quickly-create-dictionaries-with-todictionary.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
myXmlDoc.Root
    .Elements()
    .ToDictionary(xe => xe.Name, xe => xe.Value);
```